# How can i add click Event more than one in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

if i need add event click on a few div . Have to i add this directive to each div?
when will i have 100-200 card-list, The will be bad idead event click to each div)
douse it have angular directives as loop?

```
<div (click)="checkInfo()">
          <ul>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
          </ul>
    
       </div>
       <div (click)="checkInfo()">
          <ul>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
          </ul>
    
       </div>
       <div (click)="checkInfo()">
          <ul>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
          </ul>
    
       </div>
       <div (click)="checkInfo()">
          <ul>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
          </ul>
    
       </div>
       <div (click)="checkInfo()">
          <ul>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
             <li></li>
          </ul>
    
       </div>
```

Comment: Learning about the *ngFor will allow you to write one template and loop all of the eventhandlers in one statment

Comment: @JWP *ngFor Output array or object. if will be i have in html 20 button without loops?

Answer (score 2):

This is called binding, we are binding each item in the items array to one click event per div and each li is showing the four properties in the item model.

```
<ng-container *ngFor='let item of items'>
<div (click)="checkInfo()"
<ul>
  <li>{{item.one}}</li>
  <li>{{item.two}}</li>
  <li>{{item.three}}</li>
  <li>{{item.four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Each item looks like this model

```
class item {
 one
 two
 three 
 four    
}
```

Then you'd have to populate items

```
@component
class myItems implement onInit {
 items;
 ngOnInit(){
  this.items = this.getItems();
 }
}
```

Where the items function could look like this:

```
getItems(){
    items :Array<Item> = 
    [
      {one:"00",two:"01",three:"02"...},
      {one:"10",two:"11",three:"12"...},
      {one:"20",two:"21",three:"22"}
    ]
return items;
}
```